# Does an appropriate forum exist on Stack to offer a cash bounty?

Tags: discussion

Now that I got your attention, let me clarify.

There is an area of the Drupal application I am find just too difficult to get my head around or to resolve with any one question in Drupal Answers. I want to understand visually in a flowchart diagram the 'request to render' process for any page--what I want is really a document and not a text answer.

Maybe there already exists some pocket of Drupal-dom where people would want to do this, but it wasn't at my local BOF six months ago, and it wasn't in the Drupal Documentation Team the year and a half ago when I started trying to collect this data.

**Does anyone recall a project at Google with actual cash bounties for answering questions?** Or was it some other site? I can't find by a search or, alas, in my bookmarks.

Comment: This isn't actually a meta-question.  It's a meta-title with a disguised question.  This question could pretty easily be modified slightly and put on the main site.

Comment: @Chapabu Asking for ideas on how to entice people to answer questions is definitely a meta topic, I'm not sure how this could fit into the main site (it's not actually answerable in any objective way that I can tell)

Comment: @Clive Ah ok.  I read the title as being misleading to the actual post.  The question seems to me to be a sort of "How does Drupal process a page request" style question, whereas the title is definitely a meta-question.

Comment: @Chapabu. It would be a "How does druapl process a page request" question if there was a single response which could describe it. For example it would be possible to generally describe HTML-PHP-MYSQL templating in a single answer. Reading a few includes--and especially if you wrote those includes, you would be able to wrap your head around what's going on at any step of the program. The abstraction layers for using and programming Drupal make this impossible to answer exactly in one question. IMHO. But a massive flow chart _could_ express the answer.

Comment: As far as misleading anyone, I've posted here for a discussion. If I tried to tackle this project in the main site and did the work to get the necessary answers it would come off as argumentitive and pretentious.

Comment: @xtian On a side note, if you haven't seen [Living, Breathing, Drupal:  the Biology of a Page Request](http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/living-breathing-drupal-biology-request) then that's definitely worth a watch - saw it when I was in DrupalCon London.

Answer (score 3):

In short...no, there is no appropriate place on the Stack Exchange network to offer money in return for answers to questions (nor should there be in my opinion).

It's been discussed to death on the main network meta so I won't rehash the arguments against. I think the canonical reference is:

[Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty)

There are many reasons listed in the answers to that question that explain why your proposal would have a negative effect on the network.

Stack Exchange sites are question/answer sites, they're not platforms for recruiting workers into a paid project. The closest thing you'll get to that sort of dynamic is [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/).